# При подключении к AWS нужно ставить java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

Всем привет
тут читаю о подключении к AWS http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EC2_GetStarted.html#ec2-launch-instance_linux

> ﻿You must have Java installed and enabled in the browser. If you don't
>   have Java already, you can contact your system  administrator to get
>   it installed, or follow the steps outlined in the following pages:
>   Install Java (http://java.com/en/download/help/index_installing.xml)
>   and  Enable Java in your web browser
>   (http://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml) .

У меня в Kubuntu 16.4 (64 bit) java точно стоит так как 
установлен PhpStorm 2016.2.1 и я читаю в его about:

> Build #PS-162.1889.1, built on August 23, 2016 Licensed to Rover12421
>   Subscription is active until December 31, 2099 JRE:
>   1.8.0_76-release-b216 amd64 JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Это то что мне нужно или что-то еще нужно доставить?

Спасибо!

Comment: Да, операционная система должна знать, где стоит java (как минимум свободно выполнять запуск jvm по команде `java`), а в браузере - включена поддержка апплетов

Answer (score 1):

**Java** нужна для запуска **applet**, который обеспечивает доступ по **ssh**. Проверить правильно ли у вас все установлено можно пройдя по этой ссылке [Verify Java Version](https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp). Если что-то установлено не правильно (или не установлено вовсе), то вам надо установить Java Runtime Environment для вашей ОС. Это можно сделать используя установщик встроенный в ОС или скачав дистрибутив с [Официального сайта](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

Но так как вы работаете на **Linux**, то вы можете не использовать **applet**, а воспользоваться стандартным **ssh** и тогда **Java** вам не нужна.

**PhpStorm** использует встроенную в него **Java** и браузер ее использовать не может.

Comment: А можно чуть подробнее про стандартный ssh ? Я знаю есть putty - пару раз им пользовался - очень неудобно... Дайте, плиз ссылку чем и как  пользовать?

Comment: @mstdmstd putty - это для windows. На Linux вы должны использовать ssh.